# Speed up extraction of biogeographical regions from shapefile based on coordinates

Tags: r

I have followed a previous post where they extract for a set of coordinates the biogeographical regions from a shapefile. However, it takes too long to run for a relatively large set of coordinates. So basically, I am asking if there is an alternative that can do the job faster. I have tried to convert it to a raster and extract it from it with the Terra package but I haven't succeed with it.

#This question is a follow up from this post:
[Extract biogeographical genions based on coodinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74723290/extract-biogeographical-genions-based-on-coodinates)

```
#Read in EEA shapefile
#Download it from here:
#https://www.eea.europa.eu/en/datahub/datahubitem-view/11db8d14-f167-4cd5-9205-95638dfd9618

## read in EEA shapefile:
bioregions <- read_sf('PATH/BiogeoRegions2016.shp')
bioregions <- st_transform(bioregions, crs = 3035) 

#Generate points
pt <- 
  data.frame(x = c(14,28), y = c(41, 59), id = 1:2) |>
  ## add geometry column:
  st_as_sf(coords = c('x', 'y')) |>
  ## set CRS:
  st_set_crs(4326) |>
  ## transform to EEA projection:
  st_transform(3035)

#I have added an ifelse in case some coordinates are not within the shapefile 
#So the code does not stop for some "wrong" coordinates 

result <- pt %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(
    bioregion_index = ifelse(st_within(geometry, bioregions), unlist(st_within(geometry, bioregions)), NA),
    bioregion_name = ifelse(!is.na(bioregion_index), bioregions[bioregion_index, ]$short_name, NA_character_)
  )

#Try again for a large set of coordinates

pt <- 
  data.frame(x = rep(c(14,28, 3, 4),1000), y = rep(c(41, 59, 42, 42),1000), id = 1:2) |>
  ## add geometry column:
  st_as_sf(coords = c('x', 'y')) |>
  ## set CRS:
  st_set_crs(4326) |>
  ## transform to EEA projection:
  st_transform(3035)

result <- pt %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(
    bioregion_index = ifelse(st_within(geometry, bioregions), unlist(st_within(geometry, bioregions)), NA),
    bioregion_name = ifelse(!is.na(bioregion_index), bioregions[bioregion_index, ]$short_name, NA_character_)
  )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid that implementation is re-inventing a spatial join, there's `sf::st_join()` for that exact purpose. While it might not be the fastest option out there, it can still handle those 4000 points in less than 1.3s on my average laptop.

```r
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.11.2, GDAL 3.6.2, PROJ 9.2.0; sf_use_s2() is TRUE
library(dplyr)

bioregions <- read_sf('BiogeoRegions2016.shp')
bioregions <- st_transform(bioregions, crs = 3035) 

#Generate points
pt <- 
  tibble(id = 1:4000, x = rep(c(14,28, 3, 4),1000), y = rep(c(41, 59, 42, 42),1000)) |>
  st_as_sf(coords = c('x', 'y')) |>
  st_set_crs(4326) |>
  st_transform(3035)

# spatial join, by default a left join: 
# all point are returned, those with no polygon match will have NA values
tictoc::tic()
result <- st_join(pt, bioregions)
tictoc::toc()
#> 1.26 sec elapsed

result
#> Simple feature collection with 4000 features and 6 fields
#> Geometry type: POINT
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: 3739886 ymin: 1997901 xmax: 5344678 ymax: 4119297
#> Projected CRS: ETRS89-extended / LAEA Europe
#> # A tibble: 4,000 × 7
#>       id          geometry PK_UID short_name    pre_2012 code          name     
#>  * <int>       <POINT [m]>  <dbl> <chr>         <chr>    <chr>         <chr>    
#>  1     1 (4658848 1997901)      9 mediterranean MED      Mediterranean Mediterr…
#>  2     2 (5344678 4119297)      6 boreal        BOR      Boreal        Boreal B…
#>  3     3 (3739886 2126574)      9 mediterranean MED      Mediterranean Mediterr…
#>  4     4 (3822687 2119419)     NA <NA>          <NA>     <NA>          <NA>     
#>  5     5 (4658848 1997901)      9 mediterranean MED      Mediterranean Mediterr…
#>  6     6 (5344678 4119297)      6 boreal        BOR      Boreal        Boreal B…
#>  7     7 (3739886 2126574)      9 mediterranean MED      Mediterranean Mediterr…
#>  8     8 (3822687 2119419)     NA <NA>          <NA>     <NA>          <NA>     
#>  9     9 (4658848 1997901)      9 mediterranean MED      Mediterranean Mediterr…
#> 10    10 (5344678 4119297)      6 boreal        BOR      Boreal        Boreal B…
#> # ℹ 3,990 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2024-01-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>